# Would SQL Server Data Tools in Visual Studio 2015 allow Oracle DB connectivity?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oracle11g, visual-studio-2015, rdlc, sql-server-data-tools

I am using Oracle database for asp.Net web API application, I would like to build rdlc reports and I am not sure if SSDT for VS 2015 (SQL Server Data Tools in Visual Studio 2015) would allow Oracle database connectivity. If so, which version should I install?

Please advice what to install so that I can build rdlc reports.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. SSDT is strictly for SQL Server and when I asked last month, the team from Microsoft said that they have no intention of changing that.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan, What other report generator tools exists to build reports like rdlc that allows Oracle Database connectivity?

Comment: Are you actually using SQL Server + Oracle? If so, then you can use linked servers to make your Oracle database look like an extension of your SQL Server database. Otherwise you need Oracle specific reporting tools, which I'm not familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are talking about using SSDT to write reporting services reports against oracle rather than using SSDT to manage your oracle database. If I am right then you can create a connection to an oracle server:

See:

Data Sources Supported by Reporting Services (SSRS) - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms159219.aspx

You would still need a reporting services (sql server) instance to run the reports on but you can do it.

If you actually mean managing your oracle database using ssdt (deploying tables, procedures etc) then comment here and i'll delete this :)

ed

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) with Oracle Developer Tools (ODT) supports Oracle data providers for .NET. SSDT uses these providers to create connection managers to access Oracle data.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html